# WPF GroupBox displaying with broken/dashed lines

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

I have been writing a new version of my application in WPF. It looks quite nice but now I have released it to a limited number of testing users, on ONE of their machines, the GroupBoxes look utterly dire.

As far as I know they have the correct versions of .NET installed and everything should exactly the same as on my machine.

Any ideas?

[image]

EDIT: We are both running Windows XP.

UPDATE (2011-8-17): It looks like it's rectified if the affected users turn off hardware acceleration. Anyone know why this might be? Any way I can get around this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 you can turn on the software rendering programatically ([What’s New for Performance in WPF in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-for-performance-in-wpf-in-net-4.aspx))

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

In .NET 3.5 (sourced from [Software Rendering Usage in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx)). This should be coded in the Loaded event of your view

```
System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource hwndSource = (System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource) PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
hwndSource.CompositionTarget.RenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

Or you could write something that write to the registry

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics] ("DisableHWAcceleration"=dword:00000000 )
```

Note: In turning off software rendering you may encounter other issues such as a performance downgrade because of how it handles fills and transparencies ([Optimizing Performance: Taking Advantage of Hardware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613578.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something similar to this a while ago with a Windows Forms Application. I cannot remember the specifics, but the user in question had a different Windows appearance/theme setting to me (both running on XP) which conflicted with the display.

Comment: Just tried changing the settings it sortof worked. Switching to classic stopped the lines from dashing but the groupbox lost its rounded corners. Will continue playing.

Answer (score 1):

Some things which I have experienced that might cause this:

- Different operating systems
- Different display mode (i.e. Classic XP vs Vista)
- Different resolution (i.e. the resolution is not set to the optimal setting for the particular monitor)

Comment: dont forget the brush for the border color! (probably no the problem here, though)